# AngularJS conflicts with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-mobile, include

I run this simple script that comes from [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api), and it's working fine:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6uIlw6HGVVpT0amF2vhj

If I add jQuery and jQuery Mobile, then the example doesn't work anymore. The radiobuttons are not clickable.

Example: If I add these two scripts and the following CSS in the above example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
```

If I put them before the include of angular.js, then the radiobutton are clickable, but the display of the choice ("You choose...") doesn't work anymore.

Does somebody knows why is it not working?

Comment: your plunker url is not good

Comment: you didn't save your plnkr

Comment: thanx guy, I modified my post

Answer (score 0):

Use this Sequence. dont know the reason but worked in plunkr.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanx Abdul for your answer,
Indeed it works well with the script sequence, but it's when I use the jQuery Mobile CSS, that angular JS label doesn't update ("you choose..."). I've forgotten to mention it in my post, and i have corrected it now